# Modify data in shared memory when using Python's ray module

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ray

I am currently trying to parallelize some parts of a `Python` code using the `ray` module. Unfortunately, `ray` does not allow to modify the data in the shared memory by default (at least according to my understanding). This means I would need to perform a `numpy.copy()` first, which sounds very inefficient to me.

This is a probably very inefficient example:

```
import numpy as np
import ray

@ray.remote
def mod_arr( arr ):
    arr_cp  = np.copy(arr)
    arr_cp += np.ones(arr_cp.shape)
    return arr_cp

ray.init()
arr = np.zeros( (2,3,4) )
arr = ray.get(mod_arr.remote(arr))
```

If I omit the `np.copy()` in the function `mod_arr()` and try to modify `arr` instead, I get the following error

```
ValueError: output array is read-only
```

Am I using `ray` completely wrong, or is it not the correct tool for my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of Python's GIL, multiple threads cannot run in parallel on Python. Therefore all true parallelism is achieved either outside of Python when a module releases GIL, or by using multiprocessing.

In multiprocessing, this memory copy is a normal process. Not only there, but actually in pure functional programming, where arguments to functions are immutable, the solution is to always copy memory when you have to. It has a lot of advantages in stability, while paying an acceptable performance penalty.

Basically, treat these functions as pure functions.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, sounds reasonable (but what do you actually mean with _"treat these functions as pure functions"_?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function

Pay attention more to the fact that they have no side effects - they don't modify any data anywhere. They only create data.